# apache mod_jk loadbalancing issue for glassfish cluster instances

Tags: apache-2.2, glassfish, mod-jk

I have a JEE ear application deployed on 2 clusters with 2 instances each on Glassfish v3.1. These are load balanced by an Apache server running on the same machine. My problem is that I am frequently seeing the following error messages frequently in the mod_jk.log file. Can you help me understand what the issue is?

```
[Mon Jun 13 09:37:51 2011] [7116:7852] [info] ajp_process_callback::jk_ajp_common.c (1885): Writing to client aborted or client network problems

[Mon Jun 13 09:37:51 2011] [7116:7852] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2543): (viewerLocalInstance4) sending request to tomcat failed (unrecoverable), because of client write error (attempt=1)

[Mon Jun 13 09:37:51 2011] loadbalancerLocal myServer 0.062500

[Mon Jun 13 09:37:51 2011] [7116:6512] [info] ajp_process_callback::jk_ajp_common.c (1885): Writing to client aborted or client network problems

[Mon Jun 13 09:37:51 2011] [7116:6512] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2543): (viewerLocalInstance4) sending request to tomcat failed (unrecoverable), because of client write error (attempt=1)

[Mon Jun 13 09:37:52 2011] [7116:3080] [info] ajp_process_callback::jk_ajp_common.c (1885): Writing to client aborted or client network problems

[Mon Jun 13 09:37:52 2011] [7116:3080] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2543): (viewerLocalInstance4) sending request to tomcat failed (unrecoverable), because of client write error (attempt=1)

[Mon Jun 13 09:38:21 2011] [7116:6512] [info] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1388): service failed, worker viewerLocalInstance4 is in local error state

[Mon Jun 13 09:38:21 2011] [7116:7852] [info] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1388): service failed, worker viewerLocalInstance4 is in local error state

[Mon Jun 13 09:38:21 2011] [7116:6512] [info] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1407): unrecoverable error 200, request failed. Client failed in the middle of request, we can't recover to another instance.

[Mon Jun 13 09:38:21 2011] [7116:7852] [info] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1407): unrecoverable error 200, request failed. Client failed in the middle of request, we can't recover to another instance.

[Mon Jun 13 09:38:21 2011] loadbalancerLocal myServer 29.046875

[Mon Jun 13 09:38:21 2011] loadbalancerLocal myServer 29.171875

[Mon Jun 13 09:38:21 2011] [7116:6512] [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2620): Aborting connection for worker=loadbalancerLocal

[Mon Jun 13 09:38:21 2011] [7116:7852] [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2620): Aborting connection for worker=loadbalancerLocal

[Mon Jun 13 09:38:21 2011] [7116:7852] [info] ajp_process_callback::jk_ajp_common.c (1885): Writing to client aborted or client network problems

[Mon Jun 13 09:38:21 2011] [7116:7852] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2543): (viewerLocalInstance4) sending request to tomcat failed (unrecoverable), because of client write error (attempt=1)

[Mon Jun 13 09:38:21 2011] loadbalancerLocal myServer 0.156250

[Mon Jun 13 09:38:21 2011] loadbalancerLocal myServer 0.062500

[Mon Jun 13 09:38:22 2011] [7116:3080] [info] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1388): service failed, worker viewerLocalInstance4 is in local error state

[Mon Jun 13 09:38:22 2011] [7116:3080] [info] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1407): unrecoverable error 200, request failed. Client failed in the middle of request, we can't recover to another instance.
```

Answer (score 3):

These are not error, but informational messages ("info"). As you can see [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/200904.mbox/%3C49E59084.2030801@ice-sa.com%3E), [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/200903.mbox/%3C40D5E3C3CBE03D45A776E7C358BDE908F1FBD3@missoula.formatdynamics.com%3E) or [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/200901.mbox/%3C497F7D8F.7080305@ice-sa.com%3E), a message like

> `sending request to tomcat failed
>   (unrecoverable), because of client
>   write error (attempt=1)`

usually means means that the client disconnected by pressing the stop or back button in their browser during or after a request, thus Tomcat cannot send the response to the client any more.

If you have encountered no other problems you then this is nothing to worry about.